# Can you use copy_to with elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I'm trying to copy the `collection_title` field to a `title` field using `copy_to`. This does nothing whatsoever:

```
mappings dynamic: 'false' do
  indexes :collection_title,      type: 'string', copy_to: 'title'
end
```

I'm using the collection of elasticsearch gems: elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model, and elasticsearch-api.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not declared your `title` field in your mapping. If you declare it like this, it should work:

```
mappings dynamic: 'false' do
  indexes :collection_title, type: 'string', copy_to: 'title'
  indexes :title, type: 'string'
end
```